# Remove sql from html views use foreach?

Tags: php, html, pdo

Hello im hoping to move to mvc but im having trouble making templates, while i have most of it working im having trouble with queries inside foreach.

Normally i would pass $data (db-controller-view) and then i go through that data array in the html whats causing the headache is when i need to make another query inside that

passing another var in the data is easy its when i have to loop threw the first foreach result with another query if that makes sense only passed vars should be in html views.

I have also tried doing two foreach and trying to connect them together and knowing good practice would help ideally id like to have as many ways as possible to help with old procedural code

maybe a way to explain it is i have a getall model method now in a foreach in view how do i query the foreach result var outside the html this is also where linking two foreach or joining the results against each other

the code just shows a rough example and any help would be very appreciated

model

```
public function getFaqByCat(){
$stmt = $this->db->run("
SELECT `id`, `question`, `flag` 
FROM `faq` 
WHERE `type`=? 
ORDER BY `order` ASC", ['categ']);
return $stmt;
}

public function getFaqByAnser(){
$stmt = $this->db->run("
SELECT `id`, `question`, `answer`, `flag`, `categ` 
FROM `faq` 
WHERE `type`=? 
ORDER BY `order` ASC", ['item']);
return $stmt;
}
```

controller

```
$faq = $this->faqModel->getFaqByCat();
$faqtype = $this->faqModel->getFaqByAnswer();
$data = array(
   'faqs'      => $faq,
   'faqtype'      => $faqtype,
);
$this->view( 'faq/faqindex', $data );
```

view

```
<?php foreach ($data['faqs'] as $faq): { ?>
<h3> <a href="#"><?php echo $faq['id']; ?></a> </h3>
<a href="#"><?php echo $faq['type']; ?></a> 
<a href="#"><?php echo $faq['question']; ?></a>

<!--THIS LINE GET EACH ANSER FOR EACH QUESTION-->
<?php foreach ($data['faqtype'] as $faq['question']):  ?>
<?php var_dump($data['answer']); ?>
<?php  endforeach; ?>

<?php } endforeach; ?>
```

This is unfortunately all over my project i am trying to update so better to start doing right from the start here is a average example of how it looks before update

```
              foreach ($data['example'] as $row) { 
                  // works from foreach
                 <?php echo $row["sender"]]);

                  // works from data
                 <?php echo $data["sender"]]);

                  // line below should be data not sql
                 $arr3 = DB::run("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id=?", [$row["sender"]])->fetch();

                  }
```

Comment: If you're going to show us some examples, please make sure they are the same. The functions you have and the foreach seems to be completely different queries with different relationships. If you show us a real use case, including the database schemas, example data, expected output and what you're currently doing it will be easier for us. How you should do it depends on the data and can be different for different queries. Right now, the question is a bit all over the place.

Comment: I'm not sure i really understand your question, but why don't you just grab the data you expect in `$arr3` in the controller and pass it through with the rest?

Comment: perhaps what you want to do is an sql `join` so you have the question senders info as part of your data structure?  I want to help because you're new lol but it's very difficult!